# Testing toString but it's failing?

Tags: java, arrays, string, tostring

Using this code:

```
 public String toString()
{

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {                     
        s.append(i).append(":").append(arr[i]).append(", ");                       
    }
    s.delete(s.length()-2, s.length()-1);
    return s.toString();
}
```

is not passing this test:

```
@Test
public void testToString()
{
    BetterArray<String> b = new BetterArray<String>();
    assertEquals("", b.toString());
    b.add("hello");
    assertEquals("0:hello", b.toString());
    b.add("bye");
    assertEquals("0:hello, 1:bye", b.toString());
    b.add("adios");
    assertEquals("0:hello, 1:bye, 2:adios", b.toString());
}
```

It needs to start out as an empty string (""), am i doing that correctly? I'm new to StringBuilder. I'm using the s.delete to remove the trailing comma and space

Comment: The error message will tell you exactly where the comparison fails.

Comment: What is the "toString" function supposed to display?  Then we can suggest ..

Comment: Try adding FluentAssertions. Just so much more easy to read and write tests. You'd still use Junit but adding FluentAssertions makes asserting fun to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will cause a **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** in the case of empty string since you will not have comma and trailing space.

```
s.delete(s.length()-2, s.length()-1);
```

Comment: i added if (!(s.equals("")))
        {
            s.delete(s.length()-2, s.length());
        } and still not working

Comment: We can help with what we can see. If we can not see the rest of your code we can not help. Or at least tell us which assertion is failing and we may be able to help.

Comment: only the first one is failing, where its an empty string

Comment: StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  System.out.println(b.equals("")); /// is false!!. So that will not solve your problem. You should check if s.length() > 0 instead !s.equals("")

Comment: ok so this code: public int indexOf(X s)
    {        
        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i].equals(s))
            {
                return i;
            } 
        }        
        return -1;
    }    is not passing this test:  @Test
    public void testIndexOf()
    {
        BetterArray<String> b = new BetterArray<String>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            b.add("str" + i);
        
        assertEquals(0, b.indexOf("str0"));
        assertEquals(19, b.indexOf("str19"));
        assertEquals(-1, b.indexOf("not found"));

Comment: public int indexOf(String s) { 
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    if (arr[i].equals(s)) { return i; } 
   } 
   return -1;
  }

Comment: are you saying change the X? because the X is a generic, it's acceptable

Comment: The X is fine, sorry. I tried locally and worked as I posted for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're only deleting the comma, the delete line needs to be `s.delete(s.length()-2, s.length());`.

(By convention, the end index of a range points 1 past the last element of the range. This is the same for `String.substring()` for example.)

Comment: thanks that helped, now all my tests pass except the first one, i even did if(!(s.equals("")))

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do what you want that doesn't rely on any math tricks.  If the length is zero, the method returns an empty string.

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        s.append(i);
        s.append(":");
        s.append(arr[i]);
        if (i < (length - 1)) s.append(", ");
    }

    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: oh yup, smart, thats a tactic ill remember for removing traling characters